# How Read an OCR file data

Tags: ocr

I am building a tool which can read an ocr file. I am using idolondemand (idolondemand.com), but I found that not much promising. That is not reading file properly (ex. spell mistakes, special chars).

I can move to any other languages, basically now this problem for me is become language independent, I can go for any language.

I need help in building one.

Comment: Are you asking for help writing one, or suggestions for better OCR tools? In either case, your question needs more information.

Comment: Yeah, actually i need to build one.